# If Loop Output wrong

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, if-statement

Hello Everyone this might be a stupid question however I am absolutely new to python programming and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong in this if loop:

```
price_a = train_predict
price_b = df_eval_1_long_III.reshape(-1,1)
price_c = df_eval_1_last_day.reshape(-1,1)

a = price_a > price_c
b = price_b > price_c
c = price_a < price_c
d = price_b < price_c

m = 0 
n_m = 0
counter = 0
n_counter = 0 
inactive_counter = 0

for len in (train_predict):

    if ( a & b ).all():
        counter += 1
        m += (price_a - price_c)
    
    elif (c & d).all(): 
        n_counter += 1
        n_m += (price_a - price_c) * (-1)
    
    else: 
        inactive_counter += 1

print (m)
print (n_m)
print (counter)
print (n_counter)
print (inactive_counter)
```

The loop gives following output:

```
0
0
0
0
2400
```

Now this apparently at least cycles through the array. When I change the for statement to for i in len(train_predict): I get the error message that numpy is not callable

The first 5 array values of each price are below

```
train_predict[:5]
array([[1.28537  ],
       [1.2874348],
       [1.2903055],
       [1.2867677],
       [1.2895652]], dtype=float32)

df_eval_1_last_day.reshape(-1,1)[:5]
array([[1.28910828],
       [1.28910828],
       [1.29190624],
       [1.28420818],
       [1.29250741]])

df_eval_1_long_III.reshape(-1,1)[:5]
array([[1.28910828],
       [1.29190624],
       [1.28420818],
       [1.29250741],
       [1.29377818]])
```

Comment: Are `a` and `b` numpy arrays? Then it should probably be: `a.all() and b.all()` instead of `(a & b).all()`. Likewise for `c` and `d`.

Comment: @Jesper, nah, the issue is that he's checking the entire array for every item and it's always false, instead of checking each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a thing about numpy, and I'm lacking data, but maybe this will work?

```
a_and_b = a & b
c_and_d = c & d

for i, len in enumerate(train_predict):

    if a_and_b[i]:
        counter += 1
        m += (price_a - price_c)[i]
    
    elif c_and_d[i]: 
        n_counter += 1
        n_m += (price_a - price_c)[i] * (-1)
    
    else: 
        inactive_counter += 1
```

Point is that you want to compare singular array items instead of the entire array.

Technically you shouldn't even use an external `for` loop with numpy as it defeats the purpose. Instead, just calculate the absolute value of  `price_a - price_c` over the entire array (which is what it looks like you're trying to do) and sum everything accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code and the explanation. Your solution worked very well!
Output with your solution is: 
[0.4097451]
[2.82153761]
243
986
1171